# window shell (batch) script to list files changed since yesterday

Tags: windows-xp, shell-scripting, ms-dos

Any example of windows xp dos script(.bat) that when run will iterate all subdirectories and list all files that have date updated since yesterday time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you pretty close to what you need.  I pipe this to a txt file called dir.txt on my desktop.

```
@echo off

XCOPY * "%TEMP%" /H /L /S /Y /D:10-06-2011 >> "C:\Users\Greg\Desktop\dir.txt"
```

The /L switch is important because that tells you what files *would* be copied.

Comment: but i do not need to copy files. i only need to list the files since 10-06-2011

Comment: This won't copy files if you use the /L switch...it will only tell you what it would copy.